# Why were there so many icicles in this Space Shuttle launch area? (Challenger disaster)

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, srb, ice

The blogpost [Lessons From NASA Disasters: When Curiosity Deficits Kill](https://andamaninspirations.com/2017/07/26/lessons-from-nasa-the-soft-power-of-curiosity/) is about the importance of freedom of curiosity for members of organizations. However it contains many Space Shuttle-related images.

The one below presumably shows some area associated with the Space Shuttle's launch pad on the morning of the Challenger disaster.

1. Where is this exactly within the launch area?
2. Why is there *so much* ice? Where did all of the water vapor come from? Had icicles formed everywhere in that part of florida overnight due to the ocean or other sources of natural humidity or rain, or was there a local source of water associated with the launch facility?

---

[image]

Image's url includes "ss-110120-challenger-lookback-11.grid-7x2"

Comment: This is a good question. I've spent most of my life in places whose Januaries are *much* colder than Florida's and we *never* get icicles as dense as these.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I once lived in an old house single story house that often collected a lot of snow on the roof (snow-drifting caused by nearby trees I think) which did not have eaves troughs, and when there was an unseasonably warm spell with the conditions just right (warm Sun, cold wind I suppose) there would be crazy icicles, some from roof to ground. Except for that, me neither :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Knowing the weather forecast, the pad crews drained the water pipes or left them running to prevent them freezing and bursting.

> With sub-freezing temperatures predicted, ground crews drained most of
>   the water pipes at the launch pad to minimize ice formation. Those
>   that could not be drained were left running overnight, and strong wind
>   gusts blew water onto pad structures where it subsequently froze.

[Weather Channel, Weather's Role in the Challenger Accident](https://weather.com/science/space/news/space-shuttle-challenger-weather-role)

Also from Rogers Commission Report (linked below)

> The    freeze protection    plan    for    the    launch    pad    was
>   implemented,  but  the  results  were  not  what  had  been 
>   anticipated. The   freeze   protection   plan usually  involves 
>   completely  draining  the  water  system. However, this was not
>   possible because of  the  imminent  launch  of  51-L.  In  order  to 
>   prevent  pipes  from  freezing,  a  decision  was made  to  allow 
>   water  to  run  slowly  from  the system. This had never been done
>   before, and the combination  of  freezing  temperatures  and  stiff 
>   winds caused large amounts of ice to form below the  240-foot  level 
>   of  the  fixed  service  structure  including  the  access  to  the 
>   crew  emergency  egress slide wire baskets. Ice also was forming in
>   the water trays beneath the vehicle.

Rockwell (makers of the Orbiter) were super concerned about the ice flying around at liftoff and damaging the tiles.

> As John Tribe, chief engineer for Boeing/Rockwell Launch Support
>   Services, told Popular Mechanics:
>
> "I couldn't believe they came out of the MMT [Mission Management Team] meeting with a recommendation to launch. Based on the ice alone,
>   I thought it would be no-go. The ice was an unknown."

https://www.esquire.com/news-politics/news/a41604/challenger-disaster-facts/
(See also the Rogers Commission [Report](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/outreach/SignificantIncidents/assets/rogers_commission_report.pdf) page 115, etc.)

Consider this a partial answer, I can't tell where exactly on the pad that picture is.  This picture I took shows that there are a *lot* of pipes on the pad.  The quote from the report says " below the 240-foot level of the fixed service structure including the access to the crew emergency egress slide wire baskets" My picture shows the joint between the rotating and fixed service structures.

[image]

Comment: The block quote says "...strong wind gusts blew water onto pad structures..." any idea from where the water was blown? From puddles on the ground, or ocean spray, or blowing rain?

Comment: @uhoh It was from the pipes that they left running to keep them from freezing.  Added another quote about that.

Comment: It's late here and maybe my thinking is fuzzy, but how does water flowing *inside* the pipes make icicles on the *outside* of the pipes?

Comment: They had opened the taps, etc and it was running out over the pad structure.  New quote says "from the system".  For it to run, it had to go *somewhere*

Comment: oic, got it, thanks!